# Is there a way to filter two different API calls with a button?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a function to my project that filters Movies and TV shows with a button. When 'Tv Shows' button is clicked I want it to display tv shows and I want to add the same function for movies.

I'm getting my data from two different API calls so I'm not quiet sure how to approach it.
I have a similar functionality in my project that filters an array by its properties but I can't do the same thing in this case as the information is not in the same array.

Would it be possible to combine both movies and tv data in the same array and then filter them by property when the button is clicked? or is there a better solution?

Hopefully some can help!

Here's my API data :

```js
function App() {

// * MOVIE API *


//State 
const [kidsMovies, setKidsMovies] = useState([])
const [kidsTv, setKidsTv] = useState([])


//API URL 

const kidsMovieURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=&certification_country=US&certification.lte=G&with_genres=16&include_adult=false&sort_by=popularity.desc';

const kidsTvURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1&with_genres=16&include_adult=false&sort_by=popularity.desc';


//Async function to fetch API
async function getMoviesData (kidsMovieURL, kidsTvUrl) {


  await fetch(kidsMovieURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsMovies(data.results))
  
  await fetch(kidsTvUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setKidsTv(data.results))

}

//Use Effect 
 useEffect(() => { 
  getMoviesData(kidsMovieURL, kidsTvURL);


}, [])
```

Comment: Have you tried combining them into a third useState called allMovies. Something like `setAllMovies([..kidsMovies, ...kidsTv])`;

Comment: Didn't think of that. I'll also give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **fetch** you can use **axios** and with **axios** you can use **axios.all** function.
reference: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-axios-all-make-concurrent-requests/

and in the response you will receive an array of responses

Comment: That's a good solution. I'm going to give that a try. It looks much cleaner too, thanks

Comment: ya but the things you want can be solved just by combining the two arrays. in axios case too you have to combine the arrays you can simple use:
`const combinedArray = [...array1, ...array2]`
best of luck